# Present one of active child view controllers fullscreen

Tags: swift

I have a main viewController containing three separate childViewControllers. I would like to present one of them fullscreen after tapping, but I could not find any elegant way to present an already active viewController.

Would you propose any ideas on how to make such transition?

Is there a way to reuse the childViewController without creating new instance?

Comment: What OS is the app?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any screenshots, I would recommend changing the main view controller to be its own view controller (maybe with buttons and views separating it into 3 sections), and then after clicking a button -> go to childViewController.

I've found that for easy transitions like this, the Hero cocoapod is super easy to use and UI friendly.

[Check out the Hero cocoa pod here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Hero)

Good luck!